# How should I reconnect door bell wiring for multiple flats?

Tags: doors, doorbell

I live in a residential block of flats, we all have our own front door and own door bell. Every time someone rings my bell it makes me jump out of my skin, so I unscrewed the push button and unscrewed the wiring. Since I did this, half the bells in the building have stopped working. I have attempted to rewire the bell but forgot where the wires go.

It has three red wires, 2 go into one terminal together and the remaining one is on its own. The push button unit has 4 wire points, I know which ones were used because they are unscrewed, but which unscrewed point do my 2 red wires go to?

Comment: Perhaps disconnect the _bell_ next time. It's probably easier to access and to reconnect later. You could also just dampen it with a cloth wrapped around the bell (if it's a mechanical type).

Comment: Also, if you're a renter in the US, you're not legally allowed to do electrical work on the property (neither is the landlord, unless he's a licensed electrician). "Block of flats" indicates that you're not in the US, and, as I understand it, the US laws are fairly liberal in what homeowners are allowed to do compared to other countries. **TL;DR**: check your local laws to ensure that it's even legal for you to mess with the electrical installation. (Even if it's low-voltage.)

Comment: Lesson learned:  1) Never start something when you don't really know what you're doing.  2)Always take photos before disassembling.    Further, why didn't you just put some damping material around the bell itself?  Much simpler and lets you still have notification of visitors.

Comment: Worse, "block of flats" suggests Europe, where doorbell circuits are 230V.

Comment: FWIW I live in Europe (Italy) and all doorbells I have ever seen work out of 12 V or 24 V.

Comment: Out of curiosity how did your neighbours alert you of this problem without metaphorically lynching you? You must have good relationships with all of them.

Comment: Pictures, pictures..

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Were in Europe would that be? I never, ever encountered any doorbell that used mains directly. And I've been doing electrical work (including doorbells ) in 4 different countries in Europe. Give me 1 example please. I really would like to know which country in Europe is that stupid to permit that...

Comment: @Tonny Well I guess it's not *in* Europe anymore, but those famously safety-minded Brits.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Safety minded my a***, when it comes to the British (don't get me started). But even in the UK (well, England and Scotland to be exact, no experience in Wales and Northern Ireland) I never ran into that. Mind you, I've seen plenty of electrical botch-jobs, but not that.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica All the doorbells I've had in the UK have been low-voltage.  (The wires were the wrong type — far too thin — to be safely carrying 240 V.)

Comment: @Tonny well heck... I thought it was doorbells.  Maybe it's thermostats that are 230V.  (*but wait, if the LV transformer is in the house anyway for the doorbell, why not use it for HVAC controls?*)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica US style HVAC is very rare in Europe and mostly found in office buildings, not in  private houses. Central heating and HVAC in Europe (including UK) also uses low-voltage for controls. Usually cabled to the central unit and powered from there. If it is wireless it is usually battery operated, sometimes a wall-wart. There are some Smart-Home controllers with a mains connection, but these are obviously small computers with an internal power-supply.

Answer (score 16):

Go to the neighbor who you get along well with, but whose doorbell doesn't work now.

Unscrew that doorbell from the wall and *look* at the wiring, but don't *disconnect* it. Duplicate that setup in your doorbell and odds are good that will fix it.

You'll end up with *something* disconnected behind your doorbell - make sure you put a wire nut on it to ensure it doesn't accidentally come in contact with anything and cause a short taking them all out again, or worse causing a fire.

Comment: Take a picture! Pictures are so easy tot ake with cell phones that there is no good reason *not* to take one before touching anything.

Comment: It would be an especially good idea for doing so when attempting to repair this - take pics of untouched wiring elsewhere to compare them to the non-working wiring in OP's flat. Pics is, of course, excellent advice in general.

Answer (score 11):

Chances are good that the two wires that were connected send power to the other "downstream" doorbells (your neighbors).  The wire by itself would be the one that goes to your doorbell.  Reconnect the wires that were connected and leave the single wire hanging (cover the exposed wire) and that should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 7):

Surprised no one has yet said: Get an electrician, with a meter and all that, who can check voltages on those wires, and work it all out logically, without making things any worse.

If you are in Europe / UK then I would expect that you are playing with relatively low voltages, but even so, there is potential (no pun intended) for things to go badly wrong if you don't know what you are doing.